# Does Holacracy help new game development teams?

Tags: project-management, teamwork

I am setting up a game development team in my university, and we have an interest in making a strategic game based on [simple graphics](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/Hue_1.jpg). My question is in relation to the management of the team. It has been suggested that we use [some unusual new lightweight management system](https://www.holacracy.org/). Does this Holacracy system help in managing new game development teams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it - or not. There is no recipe for success. Everyone's different. Every team is different.

If it works, great! If it doesn't work, then at least you'll learn from the experience.